# how to google column chart legend bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

[image]

1. legend position 'bottom'
2. bottom text -> vertical?
   ex ) aaaa   bbbb    cccc
    -> a      b       c
          a      b       c
          a      b       c
          a      b       c

   ```
   var options = {    
       legend : {position:'bottom'}
   };

   var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document
           .getElementById('columnchart_material'));

   chart.draw(data, options);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Google fixed it in 2017. You can use both position bottom and top for legend

```
var options = {
        'legend': 'bottom',
        };

var options = {
        'legend': 'top',
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The Bar Chatr has some options that don't work as expected, and this one of them.

Please see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) for more details.